# Not getting the markup created in textarea in angular (6) component

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular, angular6

I am new to angular(6) and I am using summernote plugin on my page. The problem is I am getting the simple text or value from textarea but when I add HTML tags, It is returning nothing(using reactive form). Here is the code:

```
var markup = $('#notesum').summernote('code');
$('#noteone').val(markup); //showing text ''
```

Here is textarea markup in xyz.component.html

```
<textarea id="note1" class="note" formControlName="ques"></textarea>
```

xyz.component.ts

```
export class xyzComponent implements OnInit {
  draftForm: FormGroup;
  submitted: Boolean = false;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    noteGBar();
    this.draftForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      title: ['', Validators.required],
      description: ['', Validators.required],
      categories: [''],
      ques: ['']
    })
  }

  get f() { return this.draftForm.controls; }

  onSubmit() {
    this.submitted = true;

    if (this.draftForm.invalid) {
      return;
    }
    console.log(this.draftForm);
    this.router.navigate(['/draft-sec-two']);
  }
}
```

PS: I just want to get markup from a textarea in angular 6 like `<p>Tool</p>`

Comment: Would be nice to provide the example on how did you integrate `summernote` into `angular`. we are seeing two individual files which are not much helpful

Comment: @GangadharJannu Ok, Forget about summernote, brother. Just enter '<p>Tools</p>' in textarea and get it in component. It would be helpful for me to understand things. Thank you.